# How does matchmaking work on Twisted Treeline?

Tags: league-of-legends

I know how match making works in ranked -- you are placed depending on how well you did overall in your previous match. In normals, if your team has a premade the enemy team will have a higher average MMR. However, I am not sure how this system works on the Twisted Treeline map. Is there a way to avoid getting into games with premades if there is a set way players are matched?

Comment: Colloquial wisdom states that if your team has a premade *and the other team does not* then their team MMR will be higher. However, you have no way to influence whether the other two members will be a duo or not, just as you have no way to influence whether the other team consists of a premade.

Comment: Wait so match making in 3s TT is the same as ranked 5s SR? Ok but the other day, my team was premade and their team was also premade two on each and then well I was not obviously yet my team was ridiculously bad, I thought it was suppose to be somewhat even if both teams had a premade?

Comment: If the enemy is a really good player form playing a lot of Summoner's Rift but they haven't played hardly any TT.  Then their MMR for TT will be really low even if they are an extremely skilled player.  This would be reasons for you to play against stronger people in TT.

Comment: ok that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TT has its own map MMR but it works the same as in other queues. You basically have a "hidden elo" based on your win/loss ration of games played on the TT map and you are going to get machted with people who have roughly the same MMR. Also if you play with 3 Premades your opponents will be full premade aswell.

If you only play with 2 people two things can happen:

- You also get an enemy team who has 2 pre - 1 solo. Those will have about the same TT MMR as you
- You get 3 solo players who have a higher MMR than you (this is similar to playing with four premades in 5v5 while there are 3 or less in the enemy team).

The MMR is calculated with the [Elo ranking system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) but it's not visible to other players.

Comment: I think that this mmr thing might be very flawed it could be ok I have played a lot of games and I mean if I get a half decent team even 2v 3 my team wins but yesterday was terrible I dont understand why I should be matched with players like the ones I got most of the day yesterday it was like I was destined to lose or something but thank you for the info at least now I know TT is off limits

Comment: @Broken_Code Well the Elo ranking system is pretty accurate but of course everyone can have bad luck. Even in high elo (1950+ or platinum+ as a League ranking) you will have players who just play bad. People have good and bad days. Also not everyone can play every champion equally well.

Comment: I just did not like the fact that every single 3s game I was playing someone on my team would flat out give FB and just feed all game also the champions they were playing were not free so I dont know, just seemed a little rigged to me